# Calculate pixel value in arcmap

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, elevation

I want to change pixel values of elevation data. I want to change values meter to feet. So i need to multiply pixel values with 3.2808. How can i do that in arcmap?

Answer (score 6):

You will be able to do the calculations using the [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) with the following syntax:

```
float("DEM_raster" * 3.2808)
```

This will ensure the calculations are floating point accuracy rather than integer.

Answer (score 1):

Also **Times** tool can be use for the calculation.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012381